# Swift 2: UICollectionView - is it possible to return cell asynchronously?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in a UIView container, and I use it for displaying images (as an array of `PFFile`) attached to a `PFObject` stored  in **Parse**. I know I could fetch the the PFFile/image synchronously in my current implementation (see below working code for synchronous loading), but I would really like to make this an asynchronous process.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("attachedImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AttachedImageCollectionViewCell

        if let uploadImageFile = attachedImageFiles[indexPath.row] as? PFFile {



            do {
                var imageData: NSData
                try imageData = uploadImageFile.getData()
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print("error getting image file data: \(err)")
            }

            /*
            //asynchronously getting image data - don't know how to return cell here
            uploadImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    //TODO: show error in download
                }
                if imageData != nil {
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                }
            })
            */
        }

      return cell
    }
```

One way I have been contemplating is to have the `AttachedImageCollectionViewCell` object observe its `UIImageView`, once a UIImage file (a pointer) is assigned to it, it will go fetching the the `PFFile` from Parse and parse it to `NSData`, which is used for the UIImage.

As I am still on the learning curve of mastering Swift, I am not sure how feasible this approach might be. **So I am all ears for any ideas here, thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your code where you create the cell, you ensure, you set the image to cell asynchronously using the library-

https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader/blob/master/ImageLoader.swift

```
//Create cell in usual way
//Code here to create the cell 

//Load the image needed by the cell asynchronously
ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
    cell.image = image
})
```

HTH